# My form seems invisible to the project

Tags: c#

The project doesn't seem to recognize a form which is currently a part of the build

```
private void jobOrderReportsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmJobOrderLists cRpt = new frmJobOrderLists();
        cRpt.MdiParent = this;
        cRpt.Show();
    }
```

`frmJobOrderLists` does not show in the suggestions list when I start typing it. I assumed, therefore, that my project doesn't recognize this form.

[image]

ALSO(Different problem)

When I try to add a menu item in the menu strip of my parent form, the changes doesn't show when I run it.

Comment: @GrantWinney - Yes, I changed the name in solution explorer. The class name is the same. I also tried rebuilding my solution just to see if something happens but I guess nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your project *does* recognize the form. It wouldn't be showing in the Solution Explorer if it didn't.

Check to make sure that it is in the same namespace as you are trying to access it from. If it isn't, you have two options: add `using {NAMESPACE_OF_FORM};` at the top of your file, or reference the form with its full name:

```
{NAMESPACE_OF_FORM}.frmJobOrderList cRpt = new {NAMESPACE_OF_FORM}.frmJobOrderList().
```